# Want To Run Virtual Environment Through Python3 on Raspberry Pi Intead of Through the Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, raspberry-pi4, virtual-environment

Essentially I want to eventually create an executable file that can start when my Pi is turned on.  Currently I have to run the virtual environment 'activate' file with "source bin/activate" in the command prompt (from bash), I can't run it directly.

I've tried using the short code below to get around it (run the virtual environment through a python script, and then run my code) but I'm getting permission errors.

```
`import subprocess
 virtual_env = "Folder1/Folder2-env/bin/activate"
 script_file = "Folder1/Program.py"
 subprocess.Popen([virtual_env, script_file])`
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File “/home/pi/test.py”, line 7 in <module>
 Subprocess.Popen([virtual_env, script_file])
 File “/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py”, line 775, in __init__
 Restore_signals, start_new_session)
 File “/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py”, line 1522, in _execute_child
 Raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘Folder1/Folder2-env/bin/activate’`
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use file .bat to activate to virtual env and run your script
For example:

```
call workon venv & cd path/to/Python/proj & python -m script.py
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response.  Is there a way to write this as code in a python script, instead of having to run it through the command terminal?

Comment: Not sure, but in file .bat you dont need in to terminal. you just call(start) the .bat file